# How can I read object values in array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to ask you (I am quite new to Ruby) how can I access the values stored in array in following format (result of statement "p @orders"):

[array format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAATf.png)

These objects are result of reading xml file and now I need to read the values and work further with them but I have no idea how. Please advise

Comment: [This](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) might help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link but I think I need the exact code.

Comment: This depends heavily on what you mean by 'access'. Do `puts @orders` if you just need to print the orders on the screen or `@orders.each{|order| access_function(order) }` if you need to use a function to modify each order provided you have defined `access_function` somewhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks. @orders.each{|order| access_function(order) } gives me the following error:

 undefined method `access_function' for #<Shop:0x00000002b72a80> (NoMethodError)

Comment: There's no method or attribute called `access_function ` available for that object .

Comment: I would need firstly to read the attributes because generally it was iteration through XML file which resulted in array with 3 orders. Each order has another details like shipping address, number, date and items. I need to read this details and work with them further

Comment: Add more info to your post, enrich it.

Comment: Sebastian, yeah, I know the meaning of error, I just used what whodini9 sent me

Comment: Your question isn't well asked. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and the linked pages, and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" Don't link to data that is essential to the question. Links rot then break, resulting in worthless questions. Instead, reduce the data to the bare minimum that demonstrates the problem. We also need to see evidence of your effort, so provide the minimum code that demonstrates the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

That's an `Order` object, try with:

```
puts @order.number
# => "99503"
puts @order.date
# => "2012-10-18T15:29:37"    
puts @order.shipping_address
# => {"name"=>..., "street"=>...}
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, this resulted in that same error (undefined method...)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you need to access to instance variables without having an attributes' accessors for that. So according with your input:

```
orders.each do |order|
  p order.instance_variable_get('@order_number') #for example
end
```

For setting instance variables you could use:

```
order.instance_variable_set('@order_number', 100)
```

Comment: Hi DjezzzL, thanks a lot mate. This seems to be what I am looking for

Comment: @Petr I'm glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the prettiest solution, but it's a friendly one:

If you're using ActiveSupport (a library included with Rails), you can do a `contents = File.read("my_xml_file.xml"); hash = JSON.from_xml(contents)` and then traverse your newly-built hash that way :)

If you're outside of Rails (and are using RubyGems/bundler), you can add `gem 'activesupport'` to your `Gemfile`, do a `bundle`. Otherwise, `gem install activesupport` and then slap `require 'activesupport'` at the top of your script.

To figure out how your hash is formatted, you can do some `puts` debugging, and hammer `hash.keys` and `hash.values` to brute your way through :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh. I will try this. Needed to try it with REXML first.